# Google Cloud Search Database Connector Issues

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-search

I am working with Google Cloud search (https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/?_ga=2.124920714.-122300216.1578247736) and I am attempting to index a Cloud SQL instance. Presently I am using the guide as shown here (https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/database-connector#important-considerations). I have registered source in G-Suite. I have a Cloud Search Service Account, I tested that I connect to the Cloud SQL instance from my Compute Engine instance which I can.

My config file is as follows with the necessary information replaced with XXXX:

```
#
# data source access
api.sourceId=xxxxxxxxxxx
api.identitySourceId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
api.serviceAccountPrivateKeyFile=./private-key.json
#
# database access
db.url=jdbc:mysql:///<database>?cloudSqlInstance=<cloud_sql_instance>&socketFactory=mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8&useSSL=false&user=xxxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxx
#
# traversal SQL statements
db.allRecordsSql=select field_1, field_2, field_3 from table;
#
# schedule traversals
schedule.traversalIntervalSecs=36000
schedule.performTraversalOnStart=true
schedule.incrementalTraversalIntervalSecs=3600
#
# column definitions
db.allColumns= field1, field2, field3
db.uniqueKeyColumns=field1
url.columns=field1
#
# content fields
contentTemplate.db.title=field1
db.contentColumns=field1, field2, field3
#
# setting ACLs to "entire domain accessible"
defaultAcl.mode=fallback
defaultAcl.public=true
```

with the jdbc connection string being based off https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory. I'm at the stage where I run:

```
java \
   -cp "google-cloudsearch-database-connector-v1-0.0.3.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar" \
   com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.database.DatabaseFullTraversalConnector \
   [-Dconfig=mysql.config]
```

but i get the error `Failed to initialize connector`. The full stacktrace is:

```
Jan 05, 2020 6:29:38 PM com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.IndexingApplication startUp
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector
com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.StartupException: Failed to initialize connector
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.Application.startConnector(Application.java:150)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.IndexingApplication.startUp(IndexingApplication.java:96)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:62)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:122)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:871)
        at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$StandardBaseEncoding.trimTrailingPadding(BaseEncoding.java:672)
        at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decodeChecked(BaseEncoding.java:226)
        at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decode(BaseEncoding.java:212)
        at com.google.api.client.util.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:93)
        at com.google.api.services.cloudsearch.v1.model.Item.decodeVersion(Item.java:329)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.IndexingServiceImpl.indexItem(IndexingServiceImpl.java:678)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.DefaultAcl.<init>(DefaultAcl.java:203)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.DefaultAcl.<init>(DefaultAcl.java:93)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.DefaultAcl$Builder.build(DefaultAcl.java:466)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.DefaultAcl.fromConfiguration(DefaultAcl.java:266)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.template.FullTraversalConnector.init(FullTraversalConnector.java:182)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.template.FullTraversalConnector.init(FullTraversalConnector.java:97)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.Application.startConnector(Application.java:142)
        ... 4 more
Jan 05, 2020 6:29:38 PM com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.BatchRequestService shutDown
INFO: Shutting down batching service. flush on shutdown: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the service IndexingApplication [FAILED] to be RUNNING, but the service has FAILED
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.checkCurrentState(AbstractService.java:344)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.awaitRunning(AbstractService.java:280)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService.awaitRunning(AbstractIdleService.java:175)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.Application.start(Application.java:122)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.database.DatabaseFullTraversalConnector.main(DatabaseFullTraversalConnector.java:30)
Caused by: com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.StartupException: Failed to initialize connector
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.Application.startConnector(Application.java:150)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.IndexingApplication.startUp(IndexingApplication.java:96)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:62)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:122)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:871)
        at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$StandardBaseEncoding.trimTrailingPadding(BaseEncoding.java:672)
        at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decodeChecked(BaseEncoding.java:226)
        at com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.decode(BaseEncoding.java:212)
        at com.google.api.client.util.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:93)
        at com.google.api.services.cloudsearch.v1.model.Item.decodeVersion(Item.java:329)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.IndexingServiceImpl.indexItem(IndexingServiceImpl.java:678)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.DefaultAcl.<init>(DefaultAcl.java:203)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.DefaultAcl.<init>(DefaultAcl.java:93)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.DefaultAcl$Builder.build(DefaultAcl.java:466)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.DefaultAcl.fromConfiguration(DefaultAcl.java:266)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.template.FullTraversalConnector.init(FullTraversalConnector.java:182)
        at com.google.enterprise.cloudsearch.sdk.indexing.template.FullTraversalConnector.init(FullTraversalConnector.java:97)
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException".
You should verify the line referred in the stack trace to find the culprit variable, which should be revealed by expanding the view of the "4 more" error lines in the stack.

- [Here's information about this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).
- [Here's information about how to read a java stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess you're not establishing a connection to your database. Your configuration file looks good to me except db.url. It should look something like this from my experience jdbc:mysql://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=ExampleDatabase. The errors you typically get for other properties tell you exactly what the issue is (example field_1 does not exist in table) , but in this case it's not establishing a connection. Try rewriting the db.url.

Answer (score 0):

Failed to initialize connector --> This exception occurs when there is something wrong with your config file. But usually it tells you what's wrong along with the message.

Did you try running Cloud SQL proxy on the Compute Engine VM and connecting through that?